# Does the pthread API provide synchronization in a multiprocessor environment?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, multiprocessor

I've just started to study the pthread API. I've been using different books and websites, and judging from what they all report, pthread synchronization functions (e.g. those involving mutexes) all work both for a uniprocessor and multiprocessor environments. But none of these sources explicitly stated it, so I wanted to know if that's actually the case (of course I believe so, I just wanted to be 100% sure).

So, if two threads running on different CPUs called a lock (e.g. `pthread_mutex_lock()`) on the same mutex at the same time, would the execution of this routine be executed sequentially rather than in parallel? And after the first lock is over and the thread invoking it has private access to the critical section, does the lock executed by the other thread on another CPU cause the latter thread to suspend?

Comment: Just imagine for one second the consequences if the answer to your question were negative.

Comment: Yes.  It wouldn't be much use if it didn't, would it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.  The POSIX API is described in terms of requirements on implementations - for example, a `pthread_mutex_lock()` that returns zero or `EOWNERDEAD` must return with the mutex locked and owned by the calling thread.  There's no exception for multiprocessor environments, so conforming implementations in multiprocessor environments must continue to make it work.

> So, if two threads running on different CPUs called a lock (e.g.
>   `pthread_mutex_lock()`) on the same mutex at the same time, would the
>   execution of this routine be executed sequentially rather than in
>   parallel?

It's not specified how `pthread_mutex_lock()` works underneath, but from an application point of view you know that if it doesn't return an error, your thread has acquired the lock.

> And after the first lock is over and the thread invoking it has
>   private access to the critical section, does the lock executed by the
>   other thread on another CPU cause the latter thread to suspend?

Yes - the specification for `pthread_mutex_lock()` says:

> If the mutex is already locked by another thread, the calling thread
>   shall block until the mutex becomes available.